# Dotnet no es reconocido por Visual Studio y no puedo compilar programas

Tags: c#, sdk

Buenas tengo una consulta.
Resulta que estoy emepezando en este mundillo y quiero aprender C# pero estoy teniendo problemas con Visual Studio por que al crear un proyecto de consola con la version SDK de.NET x64 Versión 7.0.13, no puedo compilar lo que creo para que se muestre en la consola. la cosa es que he descargado e instalado la versión que he puesto aquí pero al comprobar en la consola de windows con el comando dotnet --version me aparece el siguiente mensaje :

C:\Users\unopano>dotnet --version
The command could not be loaded, possibly because:

- You intended to execute a .NET application:
  The application '--version' does not exist.
- You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
  No .NET SDKs were found.

Download a .NET SDK:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/download

Learn about SDK resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found